# Blender Bones: How to Join Bones with Objects

Tags: armature, bones

My ultimate goal is to have a arm that can move in Unity. I have made an arm in blender and have added bones to that arm.

How do I connect the bones to the arm? Is there an easy shortcut to do this?

I am very new to blender, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Blender Select mesh. Then Select armature. Both are selected.
- Control-P  will produce a dialog similar to the image below
- Consider a blender tutorial video on some well known video site such as YT
- In the past some (new to Blender) questions are cast away.

[image]